# How to set start and end time in event object for google calendar api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar api to create events on the calendar. I am following google's api document here https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#javascript.

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
  ],
};
```

My backed service is currently returning me the event start date and the time in this format `2020-06-10T10:00:00.000`  and the duration in a string `'01:30:00'`. It also returning me the time zone `America/Los_Angeles`. How may I set my start datetime and end datetime using these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Requires a bit of playing with different Javascript date object methods

Sample:

```
  var timeString = "2020-06-10T10:00:00.000";
  var timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
  var duration = '01:30:00';

  var startDate = new Date(timeString);
  var msDuration = (Number(duration.split(':')[0]) * 60 * 60 + Number(duration.split(':')[1]) * 60  + Number(duration.split(':')[2])) * 1000;
  var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + msDuration);
  var isoStartDate = new Date(startDate.getTime()-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000).toISOString().split(".")[0];
  var isoEndDate = new Date(endDate.getTime()-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())*60*1000).toISOString().split(".")[0];

  var event = {
    'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'start': {
      'dateTime': isoStartDate,
      'timeZone': timeZone
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': isoEndDate,
      'timeZone': timeZone
    },
    'attendees': [
      {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
      {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the beautiful answer, I learnt a lot from it.